# "Expected identifier or '(' before int" error while trying to use define and functions together

Tags: c, function, c-preprocessor

I was trying to use define with functions in **C** but there is an error for  multiply function's first line. It works when I run it without the define.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define multiply(n1, n2) (n1 * n2)

// multiply function returns multiplication of two integers
int multiply(int number1, int number2) { //Error in this line
    return number1 * number2;
}

int main() {

    // Printing multiply(n1, n2)
    printf("%d\n", (3 * 2) );

    system("pause");
} // End main
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you're not supposed to #define a function and then define it the normal way too.

Comment: Yes that it probably it. But arent i supposed to tell program what (n1 * n2) does. How exactly am i supposed to use a function with define.

Comment: I think #define directives means your compiler will insert code wherever it finds the defined macro. So in your code, it replaces multiply by (n1* n2) wherever it is. Function are not meant to be used with defines. If you want to use this function elsewhere, use the prototype and header files

Comment: There is no need whatsoever for the `#define` line in this code.  It is utterly superfluous.

Comment: Like a normal function : int mult = multiply(2,3);

Comment: There is no need for it here but i wanted to learn using functions with define thinking it is something that people use and i need to know it. I was wrong about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs as `multiply` is already defined as a macro. Then you are trying to redefine `multpily` as a function.

Try changing any one of their names. It should fix the error.

Comment: It worked but i dont udnerstand the logic behind it. When i use define i tell the program when you see (n1 * n2) instead use the function to your left. Which is multiply function. But there is no multiply function now. There is multiply2(changed name) function.

Comment: No! You tell it when you see multiply(a,b) replace it with (a*b)

Comment: @AnılErtürk no, your #define does the opposite - it says that if you see the string `multiply` replace it with the expression `(x * y)`

Comment: @aliasm2k: Thats wrong , there is no problem even if we have same name macro ..it is the pre-processing which caused the problem .

Answer (score 2):

Even before compiling will check the function syntax , pre-processing will happen and all the macros will be expanded .

As you have defined multiple macro like below :

```
#define multiply(n1, n2) (n1 * n2)
```

multiply will be replaced with (n1*n2) during pre-processing .
Hence , call would look like .
**Before preprocessing**

```
int multiply(int number1, int number2) { //Error in this line
    return number1 * number2;
}
```

**After preprocessing :**

```
int (int number1*int number2) { //Error in this line
    return number1 * number2;
}
```

which is not valid in C .

There is no problem having same name macro as that of function .If you will change your macro like below : your program will compile .

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define multiply my_mult //pre-processing will not break function 

// multiply function returns multiplication of two integers
int multiply(int number1, int number2) { //Error in this line
    return number1 * number2;
}

int main() {

    // Printing multiply(n1, n2)
    printf("%d\n", (3 * 2) );

    system("pause");
} // End main
```

In this example we have same name function as well as macro but still it compiles because here pre -processing is not breaking it .